# React Native apisauce can't connect to server network

Tags: javascript, apisauce

I'm learning react native and therefore I'm using an api package by the name of "apisauce" version ^2.1.2.

when backend be called with postman, I receive an array of data and when it be called with frontend application, I receive "Network_Error"

My question is what I'm doing wrong?

client.js :

```
import { create } from "apisauce";

const apiClient = create({
  baseURL: "http://127.0.0.1:9000/api",
});

export default apiClient;
```

listings.js:

```
import client from "./client";

const endpoint = "/listings";
const getListings = () => client.get(endpoint);

export default { getListings };
```

App.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import listingsApi from "./app/api/listings";

function App() {
  const loadData = async () => {
    const response = await listingsApi.getListings();
    console.log(response);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    loadData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <Screen>
    </Screen>
   );
}

export default App;
```

And here is the error when I do a console.log:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution where instead to set the baseURL to backend URL, I had to set the baseURL to the ip-address of my computer.

information had been found at

Comment: You could also use "adb reverse" command from the android SDK tools to point your device local port to the computer local port. This way, you can test even using 3G connection of your device

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).